# Problem trying to use PySpark to read a BigQuery table in a Dataproc Workflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I´m trying to automate a process using GCP + Dataproc + PySpark. For this purpose, I created the following script:

```
data_project = project_name
data_pop_table = dataset_name.table_name

spark = SparkSession\             
             .builder\
             .master('local[*]')\
             .appName('workflow_segmentation')\
             .config('spark.local.dir', '/dev/spark')\
             .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11:0.17.2")\
             .getOrCreate()

data = spark.read\
            .format('com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery')\
            .option("project", data_project)\
            .option("table", data_pop_table)\
            .load()
```

This script is used by a Dataproc Workflow created with the following bash script:

```
#Creating the job
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates create dataproc_job_name \
    --region=us-central1

#Setting up the job (selecting Python version & the source code to run)
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark file:///root/folder/main.py \
    --workflow-template=dataproc_job_name \
    --step-id=id_1 \
    --region=us-central1

#Setting up the VM
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates set-managed-cluster dataproc_job_name \
    --cluster-name=automatic-dataproc-job \
    --single-node \
    --master-machine-type=n1-standard-32 \
    --image-version=1.4 \
    --region=us-central1 \
    --scopes cloud-platform \
    --metadata='PIP_PACKAGES=pandas numpy matplotlib google-cloud-storage' \
    --initialization-actions=gs://datastudio_ds/automations-prod/config_files/pip_install.sh
```

But, when I run the DataProc job, I get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/folder/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    fill_as_preprocessing=True)
  File "/root/folder/main.py", line 760, in data_adecuation
    .option("table",self.data_pop_table)\
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o643.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

I don´t have any idea why this error comes out. In fact, I run the same script in DataProc clusters and it works fine. If anyone had this issue in the past or knows how to solve it, I will be very grateful!

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to more clearly explain the problem you're having or question you're asking. "Problem with" followed by a list of tags is not in any way useful or descriptive. Your title should be clear enough to be of use to a future site user who is scanning through a list of search results trying to find a solution for their problem, and your current title does not contain any detail that would help in that regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion, this issue is solved by setting the --jar flag in the add-job command. The --jar flag must specify the path to the .jar file that contains the Spark connector to BigQuery. The correct bash script to create the Dataproc job is the next:

```
#Creating the job
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates create dataproc_job_name \
    --region=us-central1

#Setting up the job (selecting Python version & the source code to run)
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job pyspark file:///root/folder/main.py \
    --workflow-template=dataproc_job_name \
    --step-id=id_1 \
    --jars=gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar \
    --region=us-central1

#Setting up the VM
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates set-managed-cluster dataproc_job_name \
    --cluster-name=automatic-dataproc-job \
    --single-node \
    --master-machine-type=n1-standard-32 \
    --image-version=1.4 \
    --region=us-central1 \
    --scopes cloud-platform \
    --metadata='PIP_PACKAGES=pandas numpy matplotlib google-cloud-storage' \
    --initialization-actions=gs://datastudio_ds/automations-prod/config_files/pip_install.sh
```